# Ruby gsub doesn't insert newlines

Tags: ruby, newline, erb, gsub

I have a bunch of strings, and I'm trying to replace the spaces between them with newlines, using gsub:

```
<%= "string string string".gsub(" ","\n")  %>
```

But for some reason, it just prints as:

```
string string string
```

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: It prints as expected in IRB terminal. I'm only experiencing this problem in my browser, printing with ERB.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?  I just tried this in IRB with no changes and it worked fine.

Comment: @bigtunacan Weird. I'm using ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: Here's 2.2 working as expected https://repl.it/BofP/0

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: May be you should try to use 'gsub!`.

Comment: your browser will not render new lines like you expect it to, except you wrap it in [`pre`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tags or use `<br>` tags instead of new lines

Comment: Those claiming it cannot be reproduced a browser doesn't render the same way a terminal does

Comment: In browser a new line is `<br/>` in a div or span element. New line `\n` only works in `<p>` tags while `<br>` does not. (I don't like ERB)

Comment: This question has received three votes to close it due to being off-topic. Could someone please explain why this question is not in the scope of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
    puts "string string string".gsub(" ","\n")
```

Maybe you have a situation similar to this:

```
    x = "string string string"
    y = x.gsub(" ","\n")
    puts x
```

In line 2 the spaces are replaced but `x` **is not modified**.
The result `y` has replaced spaces.

To replace the values directly in `x` you must use `gsub!`.

---

Based on your edit:

`\n` is not interpreted inside HTML, there you need a `<br>`. The br-tag may not be masked so in the end you can try something like this inside ERB:

```
    x.gsub(" ","<br/>\n").html_safe
```

Comment: Okay I hadn't tried it in irb, and it turns out it actually works there. But it doesn't work in my browser, when I try to print it with erb.

Comment: html does not interprete newlines. Can you replace it with <br>?

Comment: Ah I see. Replacing with <br> just prints out "string<br>string<br>string" though.

Comment: and inside erb? `<br>` is the html-command for a new line ("break"). Code example: `"string string string".gsub(" ","<br/>\n")`

Comment: ERB just interprets "<br>" as a string. That code you posted results in this: "string<br/> string<br/> string"

Comment: @JoeMorano That's because ERB (really Erubis AFAIK) in Rails automatically HTML-escapes text, you'd want to add a `.html_safe` call at the end if you need to get around that.

Comment: html will respect the newlines if he wraps the string in a `<pre>` tag